# Troubleshooting with a .NET application that doesn't start

Tags: .net, debugging

I have a recurrent issue with .NET applications that don't start (on others systems than mine). The fact is that I cannot, unfortunately, always create a smoothly running package. Therefore I often have to send a ZIP file of my Debug or Release folder.

My real problem is that these applications doesn't tell WHY they're not starting. I just get no exception at all if I start them from the command line, neither in the EventLog, or even if I try to print on the output the result of a Try Catch block on all my application... am I missing something?

Most of the time, it's missing libraries, or security related issues. But it would be nice to find what exactly is going on painlessly :D

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at the fusion logs? Suzanne Cook has an article on this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx).

Another thing to do (to minimise silent errors): minimise your `Main` method; the reason for this is that JIT works per-method, and if it can't JIT `Main` it can't use your exception handling:

```
/* for winform, you still new [STAThread] here */
static void Main() {
  try {
     MainCore();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     // shout about it
  }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] // usually overkill
static void MainCore() {
  // real code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem whereby WPF applications wouldn't start - it turns out that the problem was related to fonts on the user's PC - disabling the WindowsPresentationFontCache service fixed the problem.

I also found a post elsewhere with the following info...

> ...for some unknown reason, the customer had wrong entries in the registry keys that are used to build that “default font family” cache cited in the stack trace.
>   The customer was asked to export the entries under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts, and send the file to me. There were several font filenames strangely starting with dashes (---). These were fixed, and a registry file was sent back to the customer to import. After that, the application successfully started!
>
> There may also be the need of deleting your font cache, as per instructions in this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937135

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not addressing the problem directly - but have you tried publishing your application (assuming you're using Visual Studio of course)? This *should* wrap up everything you need into the installer.